# ¿Porqué el programa me da un segmentation fault? (Linea 34) - C

Tags: c, punteros, pilas

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct nodo *siguiente;

} s_nodo;

void crear_pila(s_nodo *punteropila)
{
    punteropila = NULL;
}

int poner_en_pila(s_nodo *punteropila, t_dato *info)
{
    s_nodo *nodonuevo;

    if((nodonuevo = malloc(sizeof(s_nodo))) == NULL)
        return FALSO;

    nodonuevo->dato = *info;
    nodonuevo->siguiente = punteropila;
    punteropila = nodonuevo;

    return VERDADERO;
}

int sacar_de_pila(s_nodo *punteropila, t_dato *info)
{
    s_nodo *nodoaeliminar;

    if(pila_vacia(punteropila))
        return FALSO;

    nodoaeliminar = punteropila;
    punteropila = punteropila->siguiente;  // En esta linea se produce el error
    *info = nodoaeliminar->dato;

    free(nodoaeliminar);

    return VERDADERO;
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que es en  la línea 34? En el código que has pegado la línea 34 es una llamada a una función. Quizás, como no muestras el código completo, no coincide el número de línea del error con el del código mostrado.

Comment: @abulafia Al editar, he puesto `struct nodo` al principio (antes no estaba ahí). Eso habrá *descoincidido* los números de línea. ¿ Deshago la edición ?

Comment: De todas formas, la línea que provoca el SEGFAULT está marcada en el código con un comentario.

Comment: @Trauma Gracias, no la había visto. @Mauro un segfault se produce cuando intentas desreferenciar un puntero. En tu caso, probablemente `punteropila` sea `NULL`, o no apunta a donde debe

Comment: @abulafia Pero se supone que punteropila queda apuntando a la dirección de nodonuevo en la función poner_en_pila, por eso yo despues hago referencia a punteropila->siguiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin un ejemplo de una función `main()` que haga uso de las funciones que proporcionas, y sin la definición del tipo `t_info` no es posible compilar tu código y ejecutarlo para poder depurarlo, por lo que tenemos que basarnos exclusivamente en un "análisis estático" del mismo. Es decir, estudiarlo a ojo, sin probarlo, y buscar errores.

Este análisis siempre corre el riesgo de dejarse cosas fuera, pero asi en una primera impresión veo los siguientes problemas:

- Tu función `crear_pila()`, aparentemente tiene por misión inicializar a `NULL` el puntero a la pila. Sin embargo no funcionará, porque lo que estás poniendo a `NULL` es el parámetro local. Es decir, si llamo a la función de esta forma desde otro sitio:

  ```
  s_nodo *p;
  crear_pila(p);
  ```

  A la vuelta de la función `p` no habrá cambiado de valor. Esto es por la misma razón que en el siguiente código, la variable `n` tampoco se pondría a cero:

  ```
  void poner_cero(int dato) {
      dato = 0;
  }

  int main() {
      int n;
      poner_cero(n);
  }
  ```

  Es obvio que la asignación `dato=0` sólo está cambiando la variable local `dato` de la función `poner_cero()`, sin afectar a la variable `n`.  Para que `n` resultara cambiada, tendrías que pasarla por referencia.

  Lo mismo ocurre en tu caso, sólo que ahora la variable en lugar de ser de tipo `int` es de tipo puntero. Así que tienes que pasar un puntero *por referencia*, lo que implica un *puntero a puntero*. Así:

  ```
  void crear_pila(s_nodo **punteropila)
  {
      *punteropila = NULL;
  }
  ```

  Y la llamarías así:

  ```
  s_nodo *p;
  crear_pila(&p);
  ```

  Y, ahora sí, a la vuelta `p` será `NULL`.
- Lo mismo ocurre en las funciones `poner_en_pila()` y `sacar_de_pila()`, ya que en ambas intentas modificar el valor del puntero que recibes como parámetro.
- No muestras qué tipo es `t_dato`, pero dada la forma en que lo usas dentro de `poner_en_pila()` podría ser un entero, por ejemplo. En ese caso no veo claro por qué lo pasas por referencia en esa función. En la otra (`sacar_de_pila()`) sí tiene sentido que lo pases por referencia, ya que es a través de ese parámetro como retornarás el valor extraído de la pila.

A falta de un ejemplo mínimo compilable, estos son los errores más importantes que he visto, lo que no descarta que pudiera haber más.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si el problema era ese que el puntero tenia siempre el mismo valor, entonces cuando intentaba acceder a el me da el error.